# angular modal without bootstrap

Tags: angularjs

I have been using $modal and $modalInstance and I like them. However, css got very messy and now I have to remove bootstrap. Now I need a modal.

Is there anything like $modal/$modalInstance without bootstrap?

Any suggestions?

Comment: use http://likeastore.github.io/ngDialog/

Comment: @K.Toress looks nice, I will give it a try. Thanks!

Comment: @K.Toress, how can I change the size of the modal? documentation does not seem to have such info.